# What's the difference between $(window) and $(document) in IE7/8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
doc = $(document),
win = $(window);

doc.on("click",function(){
    alert("test") //working in all browser
})

//but..

win.on("click",function(){
    alert("test") //not working in ie7 ie8
})
```

I want to know why `document` works fine in all browsers, but `$(window)` doesn't work in either IE7 or IE8.

Answer (score 1):

`$(window)` and `$(document)` are jQuery wrappers around *completely different objects*. The difference in functionality is simply due to compatibility problems in Internet Explorer; some event handlers on `window` don't work, so you put them on `document` instead.

Comment: @RobG: Well, I guess that's just the way they want you to do it with jQuery. `document`, not `window`. (Though I do prefer `window`, actually.)

Answer (score 1):

Just a comment…

Back in the browser war days, Microsoft and Netscape developed very different event models for their browsers. The W3C standardised these to some extent, but the standard was a compromise between the two and many things remained proprietary on both sides.

When Netscape died, Mozilla.org rose from its ashes and spawned a bunch of browsers (Mozilla, Firefox, Camino, etc.). Mozilla implemented the W3C standards pretty well, so web developers supported the W3C standards and IE proprietary stuff where necessary. The NN proprietary methods were dropped pretty quickly, so the rapidly dwindling band of Netscape Navigator (NN) users were left high and dry and had to get a new browser.

IE, on the other hand, had around 95% of user share so Microsoft decided to keep much of its proprietary behaviour while supporting standards where it thought necessary. Incidentally, Opera was very IE-like around this time in order to survive, and Mozilla implemented much IE stuff where it didn't conflict with standards (and some that did) for the same reason.

So while most of the proprietary NN stuff disappeared, the IE stuff hung around until MS figured they could dump it. There are still remnants of old IE proprietary stuff hanging around even in the latest versions, but some of it hangs around.

A concered effort by everyone toward standards was required to get where we are today. Note that when IE 6 was released, it was easily the most standards compliant browser around (but it rested on its laurels for way too long, the down side of monopoly power).

Perhaps MS had this one right, that click events set on a document shouldn't bubble to the window. But clearly that wasn't what the majority of those who write standards thought so they wrote it differently (note that MS contributes to web standards bodies so it had an opportunity to have its say).

In any case, it seems that from version 9 that IE does as the others do. As far as I'm aware, this behaviour wasn't standardised until HTML5 ([§ 6.1.6.4 Events and the Window object](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#events-and-the-window-object)) but am happy to be proven wrong about that.

Answer (score 0):

The window has to do with the actual program window where as document has to do with the html page and content area of the page that is loaded.

Comment: The second paragraph is unconstructive and ignors how event models and DOM objects in general evolved and work in practice.

Comment: Okay comment removed but it was still valid and IE should no longer be supported/developed. There are multiple petitions towards Microsoft to have it removed as a browser and a mandatory addition to windows as it is a humongous security hazard.

Comment: I am no IE fan, but IE 8 and lower still represent well over 10% of web users, including many large corporations, so from a general web development perspective, you'll need to keep supporting it for quite some time yet.